# Can I build a TensorFlow servable in Python

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

I'm new to Google TensorFlow Serving. I'm trying to see if I have a model which is written in Python. Can I make it a "servable" for TensorFlow Serving to run? I searched on Internet but I only could find instructions about the TensorFlow Serving client.

Any hint? Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

I successfully build a model with TFServing by following [this article](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-deploy-machine-learning-models-with-tensorflow-part-1-make-your-model-ready-for-serving-776a14ec3198). It has each you need to build a model. I think this is the hint you need.

Comment: Thank you! @蔡岳霖. If I understand correctly, the sample is to show how to use Python to create and save a model. Then load model from TensorFlow serving. But the servable is still in C++. I'm looking for a way to build a servable by Python directly.